# Show by example that R[x] does not have a field of fractions if R is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show by example that R[x] does not have a field of fractions if R is not an integral domain.

I am kinda stumped on this question. I understand that since R is not an integral domain, then R[x] does not have a fraction field because R is not commutative. But I am not sure I understand this fully enough to answer the question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Not an integral domain" does not mean "not commutative". There are other conditions that may fail. Does a commutative ring that is not an integral domain have a field of fractions?

Comment: P.S. Letters don't begin on the envelope, posts don't begin in the subject line. Put the full question in the body of the post.

Comment: Hint: If $R$ is not an integral domain, neither is $R[x]$. Do you see why?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I know that the contrapositive is true so that makes this statement true.

Comment: Zero-divisors persist as zero-divisors in any extension ring, and zero divisors are never invertible - see the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is not an integral domain,  it has zero divisors.  But $R\subset R[x]$, so $R[x]$ has zero divisors and is not an integral domain.   If $R[x]$ had a field of fractions $F$, then $R[x]\subset F$, implying $F$ has zero divisors and is not an integral domain.

Any example will do.   So let $R=\Bbb Z_4$.  Then $2\cdot 2\equiv 0$, with $2\not\equiv0$.  Thus no field can have $\Bbb Z_4$ as a subset\subring.  In particular $\Bbb Z_4[x]$ hasn't a field of fractions.

Any $\Bbb Z_n$ with $n$ composite gives an example.

---

Note:  any field is an integral domain,  because a zero divisor cannot be a unit.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).